# NDSolve accuracy related problem

Tags: functions, differential-equations, numerical-integration

I want to solve this equation:

```
sol = NDSolve[{10000 u'[r] (1+u'[r]) - 
 1.`*^-6 (r + u[r]) (u[r] + r u'[r]) + 
 10000 r u'[r] u''[r] + 
 10000 r (1 + u'[r]) u''[r] == 0, 10000 u'[1] == 3.001, 10000 u'[3] == 1}, u, r,
   MaxSteps ->Infinity]
```

the error message is:

```
FindRoot::sszero: The step size in the search has become less than the tolerance 
 prescribed by the PrecisionGoal option, but the function value is still greater than 
 the tolerance prescribed by the AccuracyGoal option. >>
 NDSolve::berr: There are significant errors {-0.000159873,0.000479427} in the boundary 
value residuals. Returning the best solution found. >>
```

what option should I add into `NDSolve` to resolve the problem?
thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need to check your equations and/or the numeric values you are using. To me it looks like this problem might well have no solution:

```
equation = 
  10000 u'[r] (1 + u'[r]) - 1.`*^-6 (r + u[r]) (u[r] + r u'[r]) + 
    10000 r u'[r] u''[r] + 10000 r (1 + u'[r]) u''[r] == 0;

derivativeAtEndPoint[uStart_?NumericQ] := 
  NDSolveValue[{equation, 10000 u'[1] == 3.001, u[1] == uStart}, 
    u', {r, 1, 3}, MaxSteps -> Infinity][3];

NMinimize[derivativeAtEndPoint[x], {x}]

(* {0.000100045, {x -> -1.26152}} *)
```

Remark: This is a boundary value problem and Mathematica typically uses the "Shooting" method to solve it. The above is a manual formulation of the shooting method, where instead of solving for the end point condition I am minimizing it to show that the desired condition can't be fulfilled. If it could be, you would just need to use `FindRoot` to determine the value for `uStart` which gives the desired value. That is basically also what `NDSolve` does internally, but as the condition can't be fulfilled, `FindRoot` starts complaining...